# How to parse XML formatted object in PHP and build a JSON object to be sent to the client?

Tags: javascript, php, json, xml

I am writing a php script to parse the XML formatted object and extract the necessary fields. I want to build a JSON object to be sent to the client. To do that I am putting the extracted data from XML object to a php array, which I will be encoding and sending to javascript. But when I try to echo the data from the php array, my PHP script crashes. I am getting the following error : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Where am I going wrong? Is there a better approach to get parse XML-formatted object in php and extract necessary fields and build a JSON object to be sent to client?
The code is as follows:

```
$note = "https://seekingalpha.com/api/sa/combined/".$symbol.".xml";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($note) or die("Error: Cannot create object");   
$newsHeadline = $xml->channel->item[1]->title->__toString();
$newsLink = $xml->channel->item[1]->link->__toString();
$newsInfo = array("Title"=>$newsHeadline,"Link"=>$newsLink);   
$jsonNews = json_encode($newsInfo);
echo $newsInfo('Title');
```

Comment: `echo $newsInfo['title'];` Why are you doing this after the `json_encode()`, anyways?

Comment: Try `print_r($jsonNews);` and see what you get.